# Lucene standard analyzer split on period

Tags: lucene, tokenize

How do I make Lucene's Standard Analyzer tokenize on the'.' char? 
For eg., on querying for "B" I need it to return the B in "A.B.C" as the result. I need to treat numbers the way the standard analyzer treats it, and hence the Simple analyzer is not sufficient.
It would be perfect if I could just specify to the standard Analyzer to tokenize on the'.' char too. If I had to write my own tokenizer with just this small extension, how would I go about it?
Thanks,
Nacha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the easiest is to create your own Analyzer. which will get tokens from StandardAnalyzer as input and further split tokens on dots, keeping dotless tokens intact.

[The package summary](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/package-summary.html) gives some advice on how to do this. 
[This blog post](http://www.jillesvangurp.com/2008/05/31/lucene-custom-analyzer/) seems very relevant, but uses an old version of Lucene, so you will probably need to tweak it. Also, see the [Lucene FAQ](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#How_do_I_write_my_own_Analyzer.3F).

Comment: Thanks, If i was writing my own filter, that filters the Standard Analyzers resultant token stream, to split those tokens that contain '.', how would i go about it? As far as I have seen, filters have been used to skip tokens, not to decompose one token into 2 tokens..